# Прерывания BIOS

Tags: ассемблер, bios, int

мне бы хотелось узнать, можно ли самому написать обработчики прерываний биос, или там уже идёт тесное взаимодействие с железом и сделать ничего нельзя?

Comment: Да запросто. Иначе как бы они перехватывались операционной системой?

Comment: Я так решил из за того, что не понимаю, как биос находит адрес курсора в памяти (видеосервис биос int 10h)

Comment: Странно... Не понимаете как, а хотите написать свой чтоли? О каком курсоре вообще речь - "мигающем" в текущей позиции, или курсоре мыши?

Comment: О мигающем в текущей позиции, у меня не получается найти информацию о нём.

Comment: *как биос находит адрес курсора в памяти (видеосервис биос int 10h)* Читаем позицию курсора, видеорежим и текущую страницу отображения, по ним вычисляем адрес в памяти. Да и зачем, какой смысл рисовать туда напрямую?